# Creating a new model returns nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a Rails 3.2 app, and I am encountering an issue that only appears in production.

While I am registering a user, my controller takes url and scrapes a LinkedIn account and populates the database with various records.

In development, it works great, but in production I am getting a strange error that should not be happening.

```
profile = Linkedin::Profile.get_profile(current_user.linkedin_url.to_s)

@jobseeker = Jobseeker.new

@jobseeker.user_id = current_user.id 
# does not cause an error

@jobseeker.first_name = profile.first_name 
# error pops up here (undefined method `first_name' for nil:NilClass)
```

I do know that it is not the profile object creating that error (I changed the profile.first_name to profile.first_nam to see if would catch a totally wrong name,and it creates the same error with 'first_name' being the undefined method).

There is a 'first_name' attribute in the Jobseeker class. And I mentioned it works perfectly in a development environment.

Thanks

Comment: Have you run your migrations in production?  Also, what does the console output in prod when you just inspect the `Jobseeker` class?

Comment: the issue is that `Linkedin::Profile.get_profile(current_user.linkedin_url.to_s)` returns `nil`. find out why it is returning `nil`.  I'm not familiar with the linkedin api but usually, the dev and prod data differs so you may also want to check that.